# How to create custom Angular Material mat-menu-items?

Tags: angular, angular-material, menu, angular12

I would like to have menu items to appear in a fully customized way (especially with multiple lines of text, various font sizes and colors), however it seems to only display the first line of text. For instance:

```
<mat-menu>
  <div mat-menu-item>
    <div>Text1</div>
    <div style="font-size: 8px;">Text2</div>
  </div>
```

only shows "Text1", but not "Text2".

How can I do to make this work?
Many thanks!

Comment: I see your code is working to show both texts. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/afzvc1?file=src%2Fexample%2Fmenu-overview-example.html)

Comment: Thank you Yong Shun, indeed your demo works. I am working with Angular 12, and you are with 16. Maybe that's the reasons? Any idea to make it work with Angular 12? (upgrading my app to Angular 16 is not straightforward)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Migrating to MDC-based Angular Material Components](https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration):

> In Angular Material v15, many of the components have been refactored to be based on the official Material Design Components for Web (MDC).

There's why the demo I shared in the comment with Angular Material v16 is working, but for Angular Material v12 is not working.

Either you have to upgrade to Angular Material v15 (with Angular version 15) or customize your existing `<mat-menu>` and styling similar to MDC way.

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <div mat-menu-item>
    <div class="primary_text">
      <div>Text1</div>
      <div style="font-size: 8px;">Text2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-menu>
```

> style.css

```
html {
  --mat-menu-item-label-text-size: 16px;
  --mat-menu-item-label-text-tracking: 0.03125em;
  --mat-menu-item-label-text-line-height: 24px;
  --mat-menu-item-label-text-weight: 400;
}

.mat-menu-item {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.mat-menu-item .primary_text {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  line-height: var(--mat-menu-item-label-text-line-height);
  font-size: var(--mat-menu-item-label-text-size);
  letter-spacing: var(--mat-menu-item-label-text-tracking);
  font-weight: var(--mat-menu-item-label-text-weight);
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-2qz8v2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thank you so much Yong, this does work pretty well!